# Approaches to predict probability of "game result"

Tags: predictive-models, stochastic-processes, games, bradley-terry-model

Sorry for undetermined terms, I just never got familiar with this type of tasks.

Suppose I have a dataset with $M$ results of games between $N$ teams ($M \ge N$). Like

```
t1 vs t2 = t1 won
t1 vs t3 = t3 won
```

etc.
I need to build a predictive model, which estimates win/loss probability in the match of two teams from the set.

I don't need exact solution, just keywords, articles, algorithms' references to start digging into it.

Comment: do you have any other data on the games? or just the two teams that played?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bradley-Terry model may be a good starting point: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bradley-Terry_model